# Hide a specific calendar header tempus dominus

Tags: tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I'm currently tasked with making a month selector using tempus dominus, however as you may know tempus dominus displays a header with the current year and two arrows to switch between the years, even when the options are set to viewMode: 'months' and the years, decades and dates have been disabled in the options at initialization, the existence of this header is causing me a headache since i can't just do $('.calendar-head').hide() because the website is a one page application and that will cause some issues down the line, therefore I need to hide the header of only that specific picker, but I can't find anything online that might hint at something.